# Facebook working app to manage friendlist

Tags: facebook

is there any `frindlist` manager for facebook. I need to manage some friend to hide my postures and about me.

Comment: Incomplete question.

Comment: As @serenesat said this question is incomplete.  I also flagged for close to  move to [Software Recomendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) as  the only complete portion of the question asks for an app.

Comment: @BradleyA.Tetreault Questions of this quality [should never be migrated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82986).

Comment: @BradleyA sorry for the incomplete question.  Please checkout the updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about any Facebook friendlist manager. But if you want hide any section from your few friends from your timeline. Just set audience as `Custom`.

- Go to your  timeline.
- Click on About.
- Click on the section you want to edit from left hand side and select the subsection from right hand side, click on pencil symbol to edit.
- Now select audience as `Custom` and then `Specific People or Lists..`.
- You will see `Don't share this with These people or lists` option, write your friends name (or lists) with whom you don't want share information about you.